# FastLED on Arduino with int[] Array

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, fastled

I built a LED Matrix with ws2812b LEDs. It is driven by an arduino nano. I use the CLED lib in combination with FastLED. It works fine!

Now I have a very simple routine here that wont work although there is no error or warning.

The problem seems to be the array which is a path of LEDs I want to activate.
So what am I missing? When I activate this on the arduino it freezes. The `getRandomColorValue()` function simply returns a color value 0-255. that one works like a charm.

```
int outlinePath[] = {30, 31, 29, 28, 27, 26, 26, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 25, 9, 8, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 16, 17, 56, 57, 91, 92, 101, 102, 111, 112, 121, 122, 162, 192, 193, 229, 230, 262, 263, 274, 275, 276,   277, 270, 269, 254, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 253, 252, 251, 250, 249, 211, 210, 176, 177, 178, 179, 175, 161, 152, 151, 142, 141, 132, 131, 77, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 37, 31};
FastLED.clear();

for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
    int test = outlinePath[i];
    leds.m_LED[test] = CRGB(getRandomColorValue(), getRandomColorValue(), getRandomColorValue());
}

FastLED.show();
delay(1000);
```

And this one works very well:

```
void progFastBlingBling() {
    FastLED.clear();
    leds.m_LED[random(0, anz_LEDs)] = CRGB(getRandomColorValue(), getRandomColorValue(), getRandomColorValue());
    FastLED.show();
}
```

Comment: What is `anz_LEDs` value?

Comment: Maybe memory issues. If you really have over 278 LEDs, that means almost 900B ram, and that outlinePath is another 142B of memory. Add some String concatenations and crash is imminent

Comment: hey...that is only the total number of LEDs

Comment: hm .... but it only fails if i insert the TEST variable. this does NOT fail: leds.m_LED[i] = ....... althought the array is still there (..ok maybe the compiler deletes it because it is unused....)

Comment: function deactivated: IDE says total size: 105191

Comment: function activated: IDE says total size: 104253

Comment: The Arduino Nano uses the AVR ATmega328P. This device has only 2KiB SRAM. The difference of your values are 938 Bytes. That's nearly the half of the entire SRAM.

Comment: well it seems to be a memory issue. if i reduce the array to 10 values evrything works fine :(

Comment: i tried to switch the array into ProgMem like this: const static PROGMEM unsigned int outlinePath[] = {30, 31, ....., 76, 37, 31};  but now i get a very weird behaviour! when i iterate over the array i dont get my path. instead i get some random LEDs ?? what can cause this behaviour??